# Android AndEngine Ontouch Animation

Tags: android, animation, andengine

I am creating an app using AndEngine for the first time. My app is animation-oriented i.e. it has a number of images which on click animate. Most of these animations are frame by frame animations. I am using AndEngine because I require some animations with particle system, gravity and other stuff. Can someone help me with a simple onclick animation code in AndEngine or maybe point me to some good tutorial since all AndEngine tutorials are game tutorials that do not have frame by frame animation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us some code with your "Frame by frame" animation? Are you using AnimatedSprite or TiledSprite by any chance?

Comment: I haven't written any code yet. I have heard about AnimatedSprite and TiledSprite but have no detailed idea about it. Nor could I find any sufficient tutorials for them. Could you please point me to some good examples or tutorials for these?

Answer (score 2):

- Before starting: note that this answer is using the TexturePacker extension for AndEngine.

For my frame by frame animations I am using a program called Texture Packer, which is supported by AndEngine. You actually just drag all your images to there, and it exports 3 files you need to use inside your project. The file are: .xml , .java , .png
By doing that i'm creating a big bitmap (try to stay below or equal to 2048x2048) with all the frames inside of it.

After assuming you have those files created, you need to copy them to your project. the .png and .xml go into the same directory, most likely under assets/gfx/ ... and the .java file should be located in the src directory with the rest of your classes.

Now lets check out some code..

First of all we will need to load all the textures from the files.. we will do that using the following code:

Those are the variables we will use to create our animatable object.

```
private TexturePack dustTexturePack;
private TexturePackTextureRegionLibrary dustTexturePackLibrary;
public TiledTextureRegion dust;
```

The following code actually loads the single textures from the bitmap into our variable

```
try {
        dustTexturePack = new TexturePackLoader(activity.getTextureManager(),"gfx/Animations/Dust Animation/").loadFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),"dust_anim.xml");

        dustTexturePack.loadTexture();
        dustTexturePackLibrary = dustTexturePack.getTexturePackTextureRegionLibrary();

} catch (TexturePackParseException e) {
    Debug.e(e);
}
TexturePackerTextureRegion[] obj = new TexturePackerTextureRegion[dustTexturePackLibrary.getIDMapping().size()];

for (int i = 0; i < dustTexturePackLibrary.getIDMapping().size(); i++) {
    obj[i] = dustTexturePackLibrary.get(i);
}

dust = new TiledTextureRegion(dustTexturePack.getTexture(), obj);
```

As you can see, we are using the TiledTextureRegion object. what we've done until now is actually loading the textures, and giving our TiledTextureRegion object all the info needed about the regions of the smaller images located in our big bitmap.

Later on, to use this in any part of our game, we can do the following: (notice that my "dust" variable is located inside a ResourceManager class, and therefore its public - this info is given for the next code)

```
AnimatedSprite dustAnimTiledSprite = new AnimatedSprite(500, 125, resourcesManager.dust, vbom);
myScene.attachChild(dustAnimTiledSprite);
```

At last, to animated the object in a specific given time, we just use the simple method animate, just like this :

```
dustAnimTiledSprite.animate(40, 0);
```

(In this case, the duration of each frame is 40, and there is 0 loops - will be animated once)

** Not too sure what's the difference between AnimatedSprite to TiledSprite. but this is how I show simple animations in my game.

I hope this is what you were looking for. good luck

Comment: I had to change the TexturePackLoader by this:
`code` dustTexturePack = new TexturePackLoader(this.getAssets(), this.getTextureManager()).loadFromAsset("gfx/Animations/Dust Animation/dust_anim.xml","gfx/Animations/Dust Animation/"); `code`

Answer (score 0):

This is sprite sheet with 8 frames

```
Player.sprite.animate(
                                            new long[] { 100, 100 }, 7, 8,
                                            false, new IAnimationListener() {

                                                public void onAnimationStarted(
                                                        AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
                                                        int pInitialLoopCount) {

                                                }

                                                public void onAnimationLoopFinished(
                                                        AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
                                                        int pRemainingLoopCount,
                                                        int pInitialLoopCount) {

                                                }

                                                public void onAnimationFrameChanged(
                                                        AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
                                                        int pOldFrameIndex,
                                                        int pNewFrameIndex) {

                                                }

                                                public void onAnimationFinished(
                                                        AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite) {
                                                    Player.sprite.animate(
                                                            new long[] { 100,
                                                                    100, 100,
                                                                    100, 100,
                                                                    100, 100 },
                                                            0, 6, true);

                                                }
                                            });
```